# Adobe Experience Manager - How can we get currentPage url into Datasource

Tags: aem

Below is datasource.jsp for adding dynamic dropdown into my customComponent dialog, I'm using this datasource in my customComponent as below mentioned  field.
Here my requirement is need to get url values to dropdown when my customComponent used in any page(this page having urls). So here i need that currentPage url where i have used my customComponent.

Please help me to get that page url where i have used my customComponent to this datasource.

```
<%
request.setAttribute(DataSource.class.getName(), EmptyDataSource.instance()); 
ResourceResolver resolver = resource.getResourceResolver();
//Create an ArrayList to hold data
List<Resource> fakeResourceList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
ValueMap vm = null;
Resource childResource = resourceResolver.getResource(currentPage.getPath()+"/jcr:content/node/path");
if(childResource!=null){
    Node childNode = childResource.adaptTo(Node.class);
    Node childLinks = childNode.getNode("childnode");
     if(childLinks!=null){    
    NodeIterator childrenNodes = childLinks.getNodes();
          while(childrenNodes.hasNext()) {
             vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<String, Object>());
             Node next = childrenNodes.nextNode();
             String label = next.getProperty("label").getValue().getString();
             String path = next.getProperty("url").getValue().getString();
             vm.put("text",label);
             vm.put("value",path.substring(1));       
             fakeResourceList.add(new ValueMapResource(resolver, new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm)); 
         }
   }
} else {
    vm = new ValueMapDecorator(new HashMap<String, Object>());
    vm.put("text","NoValue");
    vm.put("value","");
    fakeResourceList.add(new ValueMapResource(resolver, new ResourceMetadata(), "nt:unstructured", vm));
}
DataSource ds = new SimpleDataSource(fakeResourceList.iterator());
request.setAttribute(DataSource.class.getName(), ds);
%>
```

In my customComponent dialog content.xml which is using above datasource as it's sling:resourceType.

```
<dataSourceTest
     jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
     sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
     fieldDescription="Provide ID"
     fieldLabel="Anchor"
     name="./datasourceTest">
     <datasource
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          sling:resourceType="/apps/mysite/components/page/datasource"/>
</dataSourceTest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SlingHttpServletRequest` (in general) provides an instance of `SlingBindings`, which contains a reference to `"currentPage"` (I am using the static field `WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE` [dependency: groupId: `com.adobe.cq.sightly`, artifactId: `cq-wcm-sightly-extension`, version: `1.2.30`] in my example).

The `Optional` I am using in my example is a Java 8 class which can be used to avoid too many checks for `null` references.

```
final Optional<Page> optional = Optional.ofNullable(request)
        .map(req -> (SlingBindings) req.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName()))
        .map(b -> (Page) b.get(WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE));
```

A simplified/explicit example would be

```
Page getCurrentPageFromRequest(@Nonnull final SlingHTTPRequest request) {
  final SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings) request.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName())
  if (bindings == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return (Page) bindings.get(WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm very pretty new to AEM can you please explore this how it will work?

Answer (score 0):

In the code for the datasource's resourceType, you can get the URL of the current page by reading the CONTENTPATH attribute and using the resource resolver to get a resource which you can then adapt to a Node.  The node will be the content item for the dialog.  Confirmed to work in AEM 6.2.

```
// get list of child nodes of the current component node
Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource((String) request.getAttribute(Value.CONTENTPATH_ATTRIBUTE));
Node node = res.adaptTo(Node.class);
log.info(node.getPath());
```

source: https://rmengji.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/aem-6-2-touch-ui-dropdown-pulling-data-dynamically-using-sightly/